# Spring Security on GCP App Engine hangs 30+ seconds for each request then errors

Tags: java, spring-boot, google-cloud-platform, spring-security

I have a simple Spring Boot 2.3.1 app using Spring Security to manage user login/logout (using latest dependencies). The backend storage for the user/role domain model storage is Postgres (and I'm using JPA to access them). Everything works fine locally but when I deploy to GAE via `gcloud app deploy`, every page on the site--even the `/login`--pages try to load for 30 seconds then error out with the following 500 error message:

```
Error: Server Error
The server encountered an error and could not complete your request.

Please try again in 30 seconds.
```

Reviewing the GAE error logs with `gcloud app logs tail -s default` shows all normal behavior. The DB Connection to Postgres is fine, there are no WARN or ERROR blocks. I almost wonder if it's something higher-level than my code intercepting the request then stalling, like an ELB perhaps?

Here is my `pom.xml`:

```
   <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                    <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.lmax</groupId>
            <artifactId>disruptor</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-layout-dialect</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud.sql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgres-socket-factory</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.16</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                    <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>Hoxton.SR6</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

And the `@Configuration` class with the Spring Security overrides:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Autowired
    private MemberService memberService;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

        String authByUsernameQuery = "select m.username as principal, name from member m" +
                " inner join member_role mr on m.id = mr.member_id" +
                " inner join role r on mr.role_id = r.id" +
                " where m.username=?";

        auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(dataSource)
                .usersByUsernameQuery("select username as principal, password as credentials, true from member where username=?")

                .authoritiesByUsernameQuery(authByUsernameQuery)
                .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder()).rolePrefix("ROLE_");
    }

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager customAuthenticationManager() throws Exception {
        return authenticationManager();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable();

        // force https -- does this need more work somehow?
        // Still doesn't work in GAE when commented out
        http.requiresChannel()
                .anyRequest().requiresSecure();

        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/register", "/login", "/status").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/index").hasAnyRole("USER, ADMIN")
                .and().formLogin().loginPage("/login").permitAll()
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/")
                // smart logout from spring (no need for explicit endpoint)
                .and().logout().logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout")).logoutSuccessUrl("/login");
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(memberService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }
}
```

An example of a Controller with the login method is below, but I can't reach this permitted page due to the stalling:

```
@Controller
public class MemberController {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MemberController.class);

    @Autowired
    private MemberService memberService;

    @Autowired
    private AppConfig appConfig;

    @RequestMapping("/status")
    @GetMapping
    public String check() {
        return "OK";
    }

    @GetMapping("/login")
    public String showLoginForm(){
        return "views/loginForm";
    }
```

So those endpoints--and every other I try--hang until that error. The project UI pages are using Thymeleaf with a standard setup in resources/:
[image]

I'm blocked at this point. I ran a simpler experiment to deploy another Java App without Spring Security and it worked just fine. Then I added Spring Security to this simpler project and it will worked because I was instantly prompted with Spring Security's default login screen. Yet my code everything hangs and I've never successfully loaded a page. I feel like it must be something I have yet to add for HTTPS/SSL/Cert but I can't figure out what.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Fixed.

The timeouts had nothing to do with Spring Security or SSL. The default size for GCP instance F1 is 256MB RAM and that was causing enough resource strain that once I included Spring Security and a few other dependencies, the app was crashing trying to handle a request. There wasn't an explicit `OutOfMemoryError` like you'd normally see, but instead I found the Spring welcome text in the logs over and over again. I bumped up the instance size to F4 and it worked well.

This threw me for a loop but at least the security looks fine.

Comment: Big Up for you! Thanks for saving my night :-)